# How to Pass JsonResult Data to Controller ActionResult and Extract it?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, jsonresult

In my Details view, I have a "Previous" and a "Next" button to navigate between records. The following code is in my Details method:

```
ViewBag.PreviousId = _db.Applications.OrderByDescending(a => a.AppNumber).Where(a => a.AppNumber < application.AppNumber).Select(a => a.Id).FirstOrDefault();

ViewBag.NextId = _db.Applications.OrderBy(a => a.AppNumber).Where(a => a.AppNumber > application.AppNumber).Select(a => a.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Instead of navigating between all records, I need to only navigate between records shown in the results of my jQuery datatable.

For example, records 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5 may exist in the database. However, after searching/filtering my datatable, the results may just be records 1, 3 and 5. Therefore, if I open  the Details view of record 3, clicking the "Previous" button should take me to record 1 and clicking the "Next" button should take me to record 5.

In my Index view, I have a jQuery datatable. The following is part of my JsonResult method that performs searching, sorting and pagination:

```
public JsonResult GetApplications()
{
    var draw = Request.Form.GetValues("draw")[0];
    var order = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][column]")[0];
    var orderDir = Request.Form.GetValues("order[0][dir]")[0];
    var start = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form.GetValues("start")[0]);
    var length = Convert.ToInt32(Request.Form.GetValues("length")[0]);
    var data = _db.Applications.AsQueryable();
    var totalRecords = data.Count();

    --code--

    var filteredRecords = data.Count();

    data = data.Skip(start).Take(length);

    var modifiedData = data.Select(a =>
        new
        {
            a.AppNumber,
            --code--  
            a.Id
        });

    return Json(new
    {
        draw = Convert.ToInt32(draw),
        recordsTotal = totalRecords,
        recordsFiltered = filteredRecords,
        data = modifiedData
    }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

How can I pass the JsonResult data to my Details method and extract the AppNumber and Id values?

Pseudo code:

```
ViewBag.PreviousId = GetApplications().OrderByDescending(a => a.AppNumber).Where(a => a.AppNumber < application.AppNumber).Select(a => a.Id).FirstOrDefault();

ViewBag.NextId = GetApplications().OrderBy(a => a.AppNumber).Where(a => a.AppNumber > application.AppNumber).Select(a => a.Id).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: Is the Details method a C# method? If that is the case don't work with json, you should simply pass objects between C# methods.

Comment: You should also avoid doing pagination through c#. Jquery has some great libraries like Datatables.net that will have all the functionality you need.

Comment: The Details method is a C# method.

Comment: Could you show where details calls the `GetApplications()`

Comment: I do pagination through C# because I am using a server side datatable. When the serverSide option is enabled, the datatables library no longer does the pagination for you.

Comment: At the moment, the Details method does not call `GetApplications()`. I just added some pseudo code to describe what I would like have happen.

Comment: You'd just have to make another call to your dataset. You shouldn't treat an endpoint like `GetApplications` as a normal function.

Comment: Can you provide an example?

Comment: working on it right now

Comment: Did my answer help you?

Comment: I am studying it because I do not understand how to add it to my datatable solution.

Comment: Let me know if i can help you out with anything

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question. I don't recommend using Json inside C# methods, it's very useful for sending back to the front-end not back-end since its not as staticly typed as C#.

You should Create a seperate function that is responsible for getting the data from the Applications table with a custom return type. Create a class `Application` add all your properties to this class and voila you can now use that class for all interactions inside your application.

Would look something like this.

```
public class Application
{
    public int Draw {get; set;}
    public int RecordCount {get; set;}
    public RecordsFiltered {get; set;}
}
```

In order to use this class you can simply do this inside a method:

```
var application = new Application()
{
    Draw = draw,
    RecordCount = recordCount,
    //etc
}
```

To use the data from this instance of the class you can do this:

```
application.Draw //to get one specific property from the class

application //to get the whole object
```

You can use this new class as a return type in a database `Application` get method:

```
public List<Application> GetApplications()
{
    var applications = new List<Application>();
    // get all data and fill application object

    return applications
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution was to save `data.ToList()` to a session in the `JsonResult` method:

`Session["HR_Applications"] = data.ToList();`.

Then grab the values from the session in the `Details` method:

`var applications = (List<Application>)Session["HR_Applications"];`

And lastly, set the previousId and nextId values:

```
ViewBag.PreviousId = applications.OrderByDescending(a => a.AppNumber).Where(a => a.AppNumber < application.AppNumber).Select(a => a.ApplicationId).FirstOrDefault();

ViewBag.NextId = applications.OrderBy(a => a.AppNumber).Where(a => a.AppNumber > application.AppNumber).Select(a => a.ApplicationId).FirstOrDefault();
```